# Time varying (auto)correlation estimation

Tags: time-series, references, autocorrelation, time-varying-covariate

I would need to estimate a time varying autocorrelation of a variable. Do you have any references or examples? 
I've tried to search for a package in `R` but I wasn't able to find it.
Do you have any suggestion? (it would be fine also in Matlab or Stata).

Comment: https://hub.hku.hk/bitstream/10722/189876/1/Content.pdf   http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.828.5088&rep=rep1&type=pdf   http://personal.vu.nl/s.j.koopman/projects/ScoreWorkShop2013/Steve%20Thiele%20talk.pdf   you will find more by searching for "autocorrelation timevarying". Can you find an answer in any of this?

Answer (score 1):

In Stata, one can use the "rangestat" function. Assume that we have daily stock returns for multiple firms for multiple years. We want to calculate first-order autocorrelations for each firm and for each one-year period. Assume that we have a variable "group_variable" to identify the firms and a "year" variable indicating the year for which the daily data exists. We calculate a lagged daily return variable and then use the "rangestat" function as follows:

```
gen lag_var = var[_n-1]
rangestat (corr) var lag_var, by(group_variable) interval(year 0 0)
```

The by(group_variable) will not be needed if there is data on only one firm. For more details, first install the "rangestat" function in Stata and then see the help file.

```
ssc install rangestat
help rangestat
```